# Не могу вызвать функцию через SOAP

Tags: php, yii2, 1с, soap

Написали api на 1C. Скинули список функций. Делаю запрос на сервер и пытаюсь вызвать функцию:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://127.0.0.1/SGP/ws/ws2.1cws?wsdl",
array(
    "login"      => "login",
    "password"      => "pass",
    "cache_wsdl"      => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    "trace"      => 1,
    "exceptions"      => 0,
));
```

$json = $client->SrtukturaToSite();
print_r($json);

И получаю ответ:

```
Function ("SrtukturaToSite") is not a valid method for this service
```

Но если просматривать список функций - она есть. Пробовал на другом сервере - все работает.

Сайт написан на yii2

Куски кода, где описана эта функция

```
<xs:element name="SrtukturaToSite">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="SrtukturaToSiteResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<message name="SrtukturaToSiteRequestMessage">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:SrtukturaToSite"/>
</message>
<message name="SrtukturaToSiteResponseMessage">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:SrtukturaToSiteResponse"/>
</message>

<operation name="SrtukturaToSite">
    <input message="tns:SrtukturaToSiteRequestMessage"/>
    <output message="tns:SrtukturaToSiteResponseMessage"/>
</operation>

<operation name="SrtukturaToSite">
    <soapbind:operation style="document" soapAction="http://127.0.0.1#Site:SrtukturaToSite"/>
    <input>
        <soapbind:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
        <soapbind:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
</operation>

<operation name="SrtukturaToSite">
    <soap12bind:operation style="document" soapAction="http://127.0.0.1#Site:SrtukturaToSite"/>
    <input>
        <soap12bind:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output>
        <soap12bind:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
</operation>
```

Comment: а через postman пробовали?

Comment: можете в вопрос добавить кусок wsdl, где описана эта функция?

Comment: @Дмитрий, не пользовался никогда им. можете подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: Скачайте https://www.getpostman.com/, а инструкций есть куча в интернете, если что-либо не получится, то помогу

Comment: я скачал, запрос делаю. а как вызвать функцию в постман?

Comment: Попробуйте http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/08/22/making-soap-requests-using-postman/, хотя я обычно рекомендую использовать SoapUI. Она по WSDL сама создаст для вас нужные шаблоны запросов которые нужно будет заполнить.